# cambiar clase de un boton de acuerdo con un select con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

espero puedan ayudarme.
Tengo en una tabla un select y un boton. El select tiene un option vacio, otro que dice Mejor empleo y otro que dice Inicio negocio.

Quiero que cuando seleccione Mejor empleo ó Inició negocio el boton se ponga verde al quitar la clase .btn-danger del boton y agregar .btn-success. Esto ya lo logro.

Lo que me falta es que al seleccionar el espacio vacio, quite los cambios y vuelva a tener su clase .btn-danger.  Es decir, que esté como al principio.

HTML

```
  <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Pais</th>
                <th>Estaca</th>
                <th>Barrio</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Educación</th>
                <th>Oficio</th>
                <th>Conocimiento</th>
                <th>Aspiraciones</th>
                <th>Inicio</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
                <th>Nuevo status</th>
                <th>Enviar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)): ?>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $ver[0];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[1];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[2];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[3];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[4];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[5];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[6];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[7];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[8];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[9];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[10]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[11]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[12]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ver[13]; ?></td>
                <td><select name="" id="nuevoStatus" onchange="cambiarBtn(this.value);"  >
                    <option value="0"> </option>
                    <option value="Empleo">Empleo</option>
                    <option value="Negocio">Negocio</option>
                    <input type="text" id="seleccion" >
                </select></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="botonAS">
                        <input type="button" id="enviar" class="btn btn-danger" value="Autosuficiente" >
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

SCRIPT

```
function cambiarBtn(){

    var option = document.getElementById('#nuevoStatus');

    if (option != 0) {
        $("#enviar").removeClass("btn-danger");
        $("#enviar").addClass("btn-success");

    } else if (option = 0) {
        $("#enviar").removeClass("btn-success");
        $("#enviar").addClass("btn-warning");
    }
}
```

Comment: El else.if debe tener doble igual.   Es decir option==0

Comment: Hice lo que me sugirieron y nada, sigue igual, cambia a verde el boton pero luego al seleccionar el primer option no regresa a rojo. Es decir, la sintaxis con el operador si puede mejorar pero no es la solucion, Y si en vez de comparar con '0' comparo directamente con el valor del option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes un error en el segundo *if*

Debe ser

```
else if (option == 0) {...
```

Con dos iguales **==**

Pero es mejor práctica hacer comparaciones en JS de esta manera:

```
option === 0
option !== 0
```

Es para asegurarte que estas comparando el mismo tipo de tato
Ejemplo:

Si option es un string.
option = '1'

```
option == 1 // true
option === 1 // false
```

Con eso te vas evitar algunos dolores de cabeza

La solución completa la encuentras acá:
https://codepen.io/oscarmyepes/pen/dyPbjbe

Comment: Hice lo que me sugirieron y nada, sigue igual, cambia a verde el boton pero luego al seleccionar el primer option no regresa a rojo. Es decir, la sintaxis con el operador si puede mejorar pero no es la solucion, Y si en vez de comparar con '0' comparo directamente con el valor del option?

Comment: Mira este ejemplo, estás leyendo mal el value del select https://codepen.io/oscarmyepes/pen/dyPbjbe

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, ya entendí y me funcionó. Sería bueno que lo coloques en la respuesta para que esté disponible para otros

Answer (score 1):

```
function cambiarBtn(){

    var option = document.getElementById('#nuevoStatus');

    if (option != 0) { //aqui deberias usar una sentencia !==
        $("#enviar").removeClass("btn-danger");
        $("#enviar").addClass("btn-success");

    } else if (option = 0) { //Aqui tienes un error ya que en ves de comparar estas igualando
        $("#enviar").removeClass("btn-success");
        $("#enviar").addClass("btn-warning");
    }
}
```